# Domain of triangular region for double integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

This is probably a silly question from my over-thinking the problem, but in most solutions to this problem, why is the domain for $x$ from 0 to 1 instead of 0 to 2?

> Find the mass and centre of mass of the lamina that occupies the region $D$ and has the given density function $p$.
>
> D is the triangular region with vertices $(0,0), (2,1), (0,3)$; $p(x,y) = 7(x + y)$

Almost every solution I've seen gives $0≤x≤1; \frac{1}{2} x ≤ y ≤ 3 - x$. The $y$ limits make perfect sense; $x$, less so.

Comment: Looks incorrect to me. It should be $0\le x\le 2$, $\frac{1}{2}x\le y\le 3-x$.

Comment: That's what I thought as well—perhaps it's an error in the answer key to this set. I'll try to verify.

Answer (score 1):

Either of these will do it:
$$
\underbrace{\int_0^2 \left( \int_{\frac 1 2 x}^{3-x} \cdots\cdots \, dy \right) \,dx} \quad \text{or} \quad \underbrace{ \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^{2y} \cdots\cdots\,dx \right) \,dy + \int_1^3 \left( \int_0^{3-y} \cdots\cdots\,dx \right) \, dy}
$$
I'd have said the bounds $0\le x\le 1$ are probably a typographical error, but for the words "almost every solution I've seen", which makes me wonder where you're finding these solutions.